# Sharing data in Controller in the example - AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, function, service, controller

Making simple program to share data as input in one to be updated in other through custom service only. I am writing bit of code I can, but need help to get it working for both controllers. Can someone help?

**SNIPPET:**

```
<html>

<head> 
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script> 
</head> 

<body ng-app="myApp"> 

<div class="div1" ng-controller="myCtrl1"> 
    <input type="text" ng-model="name"> <span>{{name}}</span>
</div> 

<div class="div2" ng-controller="myCtrl2"> 
    <span>{{name}}</span> 
</div> 

<script> 
//app declaration
var app = angular.module("myApp",[]);

//controllers declaration
app.controller('myCtrl1',function($scope, dummyService){
    $scope.name = "Peter";
});

app.controller('myCtrl2',function($scope, dummyService){
    $scope.name = "Roger";
});

//service declaration
app.service('dummyService',function(){
    this.name = "Martin";
});

</script> 

</body> 

</html>
```

**REQUIREMENT:**

> As soon as I start typing text in input box. It must start updating the same immediately in both the spans (viz in div1 and in div2).

Comment: Is no one capable of answering the question? Alas ... ;(

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21919962/share-data-between-angularjs-controllers

Comment: @Peterson I'm on the way :)

Comment: So the most active person at SO .. speaks up! ;)

Comment: @MichałStyś: Already, saw that before posting!

Comment: For your requirement you can use $rootScope , But I dont know if it is best to do

Comment: Hmmm .... wanted to use Service for this only! For experience .. and heard it is best method for data sharing in AngularJs!

Comment: @Peterson Yes, I felt bad, after 15 mins no one answered this, So I did it for you, Thanks :) Please check updated answer I update both the way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp",[]);

//controllers declaration
app.controller('myCtrl1',function($scope, dummyService, $rootScope){
    $scope.name = "Peter";
    $scope.change = function() {
      $rootScope.$emit('changeName',{name:$scope.name});
    }
});

app.controller('myCtrl2',function($scope, dummyService, $rootScope){
    $scope.name = "Roger";
    $rootScope.$on('changeName', function(event,data) {
      $scope.name = data.name;
    })
});

//service declaration
app.service('dummyService',function(){
    this.name = "Martin";
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp"> 

<div class="div1" ng-controller="myCtrl1"> 
    <input type="text" ng-model="name" ng-change="change()"> <span>{{name}}</span>
</div> 

<div class="div2" ng-controller="myCtrl2"> 
    <span>{{name}}</span> 
</div> 
 
</body>
```

Comment: Polluting $rootScope would be a bad idea

Comment: This works ... GG good! Though I think Pankaj is right, but pankaj your code above not working out in plunker!

Answer (score 1):

1st thing you haven't binded service variable with `$scope` variable, but that is not going to fix it.

The problem is, you are using primitive type variable where you assigned new value to variable each time it changes the reference of that object. You can solve this problem easily by changing it to reference type object. There by binding object references you ensure that whenever object properties changes it will change the copy of underlying object which it points to. Likewise here we pointed our service `model` variable with `scope`'s `model` object they will ensure to keep in sync.

**Markup**

```
<body ng-app="myApp">

  <div class="div1" ng-controller="myCtrl1">
    <input type="text" ng-model="model.name"> <span>{{name}}</span>
  </div>

  <div class="div2" ng-controller="myCtrl2">
    <span>{{model.name}}</span>
  </div>

</body>
```

**Code**

```
app.controller('myCtrl1', function($scope, dummyService) {
  $scope.model = dummyService.model;
});

app.controller('myCtrl2', function($scope, dummyService) {
  $scope.model = dummyService.model;
});

//service declaration
app.service('dummyService', function() {
  this.model = {
    name: "Martin"
  };
});
```

[**Demo**](https://plnkr.co/edit/Qfyx3gbGStrtINpi9CD4?p=preview)

---

You can achieve the same thing with `primitive` type as well, with what you had in your question. But for the same you have to write `getter` & `setter` to set variable value. You could change service to below

```
app.service('dummyService', function() {
  var self = this;
  var name = "Martin"; //private variable

  self.setName = function(name) {
    name = name;
  }
  self.getName = function() {
    return name;
  }
});
```

[**Plunkr Here**](https://plnkr.co/edit/JJCSQjtWDgNKOIIvGIg5?p=preview)

Comment: Pankaj in Plunker the value is not getting updated in second div as is filled and seen changed in first div! Pl check ...

Comment: Both of your fiddles are not working. Pl, have a view! (Try change text in input)

Comment: @Peterson plunkr seems down. http://www.isitdownrightnow.com/plnkr.co.html

Comment: P - Thanks Buddy!

Comment: @Peterson now they are fixed, Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this through method reference. Considering, you need to initialize both name variables with different values. Otherwise, you can simply use service variable.($scope.name = dummyService.name)

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp",[]);

//controllers declaration
app.controller('myCtrl1',function($scope, dummyService, $rootScope){
    $scope.name = "Peter";
    $scope.change = function() {
      dummyService.setName($scope.name);
    }
    
    
});

app.controller('myCtrl2',function($scope, dummyService, $rootScope){
    $scope.name = "Roger";
    $scope.change = function(name) {
      $scope.name =  name;
    }
    $scope.init = function() {
      dummyService.set($scope.change);
    }
    $scope.init();
});

//service declaration
app.service('dummyService',function(){
    this.name = "Martin";
    this.set = function(method) {
      this.setName = method;
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp"> 

<div class="div1" ng-controller="myCtrl1"> 
    <input type="text" ng-model="name" ng-change="change()"> <span>{{name}}</span>
</div> 

<div class="div2" ng-controller="myCtrl2"> 
    <span>{{name}}</span> 
</div> 
 
</body>
```